# What resources are helpful to a SCOM Administrator

Tags: scom

What websites and resources are helpful for a SCOM administrator?

Based on my own research I found the following links helpful:

Software: [Quest Extensions Manager](http://www.quest.com/quest-management-xtensions-operations-manager/)

Community site/Blob: [Everything Systems Center](http://www.scom2k7.com), and [SCOM Blog](http://opsmgr.wordpress.com/)

Comment: Sheer *luck*. That's what a SCOM administrator really needs.

Answer (score 4):

I've got these bookmarked...

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/systemcenter/om/bb498235

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310604.aspx

(I'm a new member here, it wouldn't let me post more than two links)

Comment: There is a tonne of good resources on the Technet sites (blogs, etc).  Technet is always a good place to start.

Comment: @Madhouse987 Thanks! If you want to send them to me, I'd appreciate it, and will update your post!  Just send to my name at gmail.

Answer (score 2):

Have the OpsMgr 2007 guides on your computer

Supported configurations,
Quick Start Guide,
Security Guide,
Design Guide,
Deployment Guide,
Migration Guide,
Admin Guide,
Users Guide.

Buy these books and get familiar with them.

***System Center Operations Manager 2007 Unleashed by Kerrie Meyler, Cameron Fuller, John Joyner, and Andy Dominey***

and

***System Center Operations Manager (OpsMgr) 2007 R2 Unleashed: Supplement to System Center Operations Manager 2007 Unleashed by Kerrie Meyler, Cameron Fuller, John Joyner, and Andy Dominey***